# How to overdrive a signal?

Tags: amplifier, signal, signal-processing, lm386

I am planning to build this circuit below as a electric guitar amplifier.
[image]

[Source](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf?ts=1606542966695&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

And I also would like to add

- gain control
- overdrive channel

to existing design.

I have simulated this circuit on LTSPice as follows:

- I have installed 10k potentiometer between gain pins. It worked fine
  on simulation but is it an effective way to control gain?
- Other question is I
  would like to add an overdrive channel to this amplifier circuit
  which will clip the input signal after amplification. For this I have
  tried placing two opposite directioned diodes parallel to bypass 0.05
  \$\mu\$F capacitor but it failed. How could I add an extra overdrive
  channel with overdrive control?

Comment: What is "overdrive" in this context?

Comment: "Distortion and overdrive are forms of audio signal processing used to alter the sound of amplified electric musical instruments, usually by increasing their gain, producing a "fuzzy", "growling", or "gritty" tone."S:Wikipedia Eventually clipping of singal.

Comment: Okay, but how do you intend to implement it and what do you want us to do to help? I doubt most people here are familiar with audio electronics and especially not terminology for electric guitar effects.

Comment: In sold guitar amplifiers there are two channels. One is clean and one is distortion (overdrive). Here I took TI's design for clean channel and I want to add a "clipping" channel to this circuit. I tried it using diodes on simulation but failed. So I asked how to implement this clipping effect and thanks to @Andy Aka his answer helped a lot. As I know it is impossible or very difficult to soft clip with solid state devices. So I was trying to implement "hard clipping"

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 10 kohm input impedance is far too low for an electric guitar to be connected without serious loss of high frequencies. You need a buffer amplifier that has a high input impedance usually between 1 Mohm and 10 Mohm.

> *And I also would like to add gain control*

If you add a buffer amplifier, the 10 kohm pot will serve as a proper gain control. In other words you don't need to add a gain control because there is one right there on your circuit at the left but you need a buffer amplifier between it and the guitar input. Once you have an op-amp as a buffer you can add another op-emp to perform the action of clipping/distortion/overdrive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkfAvg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> *I have installed 10k potentiometer between gain pins. It worked fine
> on simulation but is it an effective way to control gain?*

Your circuit has a gain control already; you don't need to add another.

> *How could I add an extra overdrive channel with overdrive control?*

I've shown where it should go and there are many op-amp circuits on the web that can be used such as this one: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/davidmorrin.com/www/home/trouble/troubleeffects/distortion-overdrive/op-amp-distortion-and-overdrive).

Input buffer with 1.5 Mohm input impedance: -

[image]

The one above shows a JFET buffer amp and it's connected to an LM386 AND (incidentally) it shows an alternative way to wire a pot to the LM386 (like your original question). Image from [here](https://robrobinette.com/How_the_Ruby_Amp_Works.htm).

There are plenty of on-line resources if you choose to look such as this one with tone controls and buffer amp: -

[image]

Image from [this site](http://www.redcircuits.com/Page145.htm) (with full parts list).

Answer (score 2):

You have gain control - it's the pot in in the input. I guess you want something that makes overdrive sound possible without max output volume, but also with max volume, if needed. To get it you need a separate clipping circuit. The classic guitar amp overdrive with that functionality happens in the separate preamp which should be inserted in front of the current circuit. The preamp has its own gain control which determines if the signal is overdriven or not. The current potentiometer would be the "master volume".

There can be a special clipping diode circuit or amplifying parts themselves can cause the wanted distortion when driven too hard. The latter idea works with valve triode preamps but in simple transistor preamps the result is easily so called "fuzz effect" which can work with single notes, but makes even power chords to untolerable smeared mass.

This already tells that the preamp isn't trivial. In addition passive guitar pickups have substantial treble loss if they are loaded with too low resistance (as said already by others) and the right sounding overdrive principle depends on music style. You will need also at least bass & treble knobs to have some control on the frequency response.

I guess you should search for known good designs. Many full schematics of well known amplifiers and effect pedals are easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. It is a grear idea to look elder guitar amplifiers to get ideas. Fender has a lot of schematics on the internet. Years ago they had it on his web, but now you need to google it.

One clasic way to do distortion without valves is to put antiparallel diodes on opamp feedback, like tubescreamer does. You can use normal diodes or zeners.

Take a look here: http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/how-to-build-it/technical-help/articles/design-distortion/

And here:
https://www.electrosmash.com/tube-screamer-analysis